# Centered table text not aligned with multirow and cite

Tags: tables, citing, multirow, cite-package

When I center a tabular column, it does not align correctly when I mix `\multirow` with `\cite`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\cite{lamport94} \\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\cite{lamport94}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94} Dummy
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The table renders like:

[image: table]

I would have expected that the text is perfectly aligned.

It seems that the `cite` package causes this.
When I remove `\usepackage{cite}`, the problem disappears.

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: With `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`, you don't have the problem. Probably, the package `cite` consider that a command `\cite` should follow a word.

Comment: Indeed, the `cite` is causing it. The first `\cite{}` inside the `\mbox{}` also adds the extra space. So then they are perfectly aligned but of the centre.